# Display pie chart at order invoice grid

Tags: magento2, grid, invoice, sales-invoice

I want to display the pig chart on the invoice grid and the pie chart should be updated after applying the filer in the grid.

Well, I am able to display the Pie chart on the sales order invoice grid with the help of layout/templates. But I am not able to update the chart by applying the filter because filter loads by UI component.

Any approach or idea?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can your try this blog.It can be done by knockoutjs ..

https://www.aurigait.com/how-to-create-magento2-knockout-chart/

And charts you can draw are http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/